# Mysql - does not save proper encoding

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been having this problem for a while. The problem is, I can't save an username to MySQL field. Correct username: *Vėdarėlis*

Field result: *VÄ—darÄ—lis*

As you can see below, my collation is set to utf8
[image]

And I'm pretty sure the PHP itself is working fine, because in the general mysql log, I have this line:

```
168308 Query    UPDATE users_steam SET name='Vėdarėlis', ......rest of the query....
```

So how do I properly set user name with proper encoding? Thanks

Comment: Run this query before inserting `SET NAMES UTF8`

Comment: Can I place it in the same query as the UPDATE?

Comment: No,but you only need to run it once unless you restart the server or edit you mysql config to always use utf8 connection